# R1C1 Formula: Using Row counter for R[ ]

Tags: vba, excel, countif

Im trying to use a row counter to make my range for the countif. Its giving me an error every time I run it and I suspect that its a syntax error. Any thoughts?

```
Dim nRows As Integer 'row counter
nRows = Range(Range("B4"), Range("B4").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

Range("Y5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
  "=IF(COUNTIF("R5C5:R" & nRows & "C5",RC[-20])>=2,""Duplicate Account Combination"","""")"
Range("Y5").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Y5:Y" & nRows)
```

I believe the issue is at the `"=IF(COUNTIF("R5C5:R" & nRows & "C5",RC[-20])>=2,"` part of the code.

Comment: @OpiesDad, sorry I deleted your edit.  I open ~30 tabs at once and work my way through.  Must have had an old page that let me get an edit in before you.  VossWater, hopefully this is consistent with what you wanted to say.

Comment: in the future, provide your error message.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is in fact in the line you suspected it was.  The problem is that you are escaping the string at the wrong time.  You need to change the quotation marks as such:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(COUNTIF(R5C5:R" & nRows & "C5,RC[-20])>=2,""Duplicate Account Combination"","""")"
```

Note that to debug this, the easiest way would be to set this equal to a string, such as:

```
Dim teststring
teststring = "=IF(COUNTIF(R5C5:R" & nRows & "C5,RC[-20])>=2,""Duplicate Account Combination"","""")"
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = teststring
```

This way if something isn't working, you can debug.print teststring and then paste this string into the actual excel cell.  This will make it much easier to see the problem.

While you are testing it, note that you need to make sure that excel is set to R1C1 notation, otherwise this will cause an error while testing.  Per Byron Wall's comment, you don't need it set in this style for the VBA to work, but you do if you are actually pasting it into excel to test.

Comment: Excel does not need to be set to `R1C1` in order for formulas entered using `.FormulaR1C1` to work correctly.  The rest of this look good.

Comment: @Byron Wall Ahhh, good point. Didn't realize that...I had an error while trying to paste the formula into excel manually when not in R1C1 style, but the VBA does indeed work while in either setting.

Comment: Yea I understand.  You can cheat and use `.FormulaR1C1` to set it while testing.  Even easier is to write it in A1 notation and just call `.FormulaR1C1` to let Excel translate if for you.  There is also `Application.ConvertFormula` to do the same thing more officially.